# How to stop persistence from altering database, JPA

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel, openjpa

I am using camel and open jpa as persistent provider, but I don't want alter statements to be run on prduction.
Snapshot of persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="camel-openjpa-oracle-alert" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">              
.
.
<provider>
            org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
        </provider>   
<properties>
 <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=false)" />
</properties>
.
.    
</persistence-unit>
```

What value we have to put for `openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings`, so that alter command are not executed.

I searched but was unable to find any such value.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to know a little more about what you are doing and why you need to use SynchronizeMappings.  The fact that you use ForeignKeys=true tells me you want OpenJPA to read you schema and determine if you have any database FKs defined (i.e. so OpenJPA knows about these FKs so it can order SQL properly to honor parent/child FK constraints).  This is a perfectly valid use of SynchMappings.  However, by using 'buildSchema', you are specifically telling OpenJPA to make "the database schema match your existing mappings"....this comment is lifted from this OpenJPA doc:

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_mapping.html#ref_guide_mapping_synch

Therefore, you are specifically telling OpenJPA to update your database schema.  You can remove the 'buildSchema' if you don't want OpenJPA to update your schema to match your domain model.  That is, try:

Or you could use 'validate' in place of 'buildSchema'....however, as the above doc states, OpenJPA will throw an exception if it finds a schema/domain mismatch which may not be what you want.  I suggest you read the above doc, and look at the available options to you.

Thanks,

Heath Thomann